# Blocking until event

Tags: javascript, blocking

In a web worker, I'm firing off a postMessage() and need to wait for the result before continuing execution. Is there anyway of blocking until the onMessage event occurs, short of busy waiting plus something like Peterson's Algorithm?

Comment: "I'm a web worker", sounds cheesy.. lol

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to break up your script into two parts and fire the second part when the message comes back. That is how any asynchronous call works in the JavaScript world.